# React map API response data to Typescript object

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I'm calling an API call that returns response data that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "code": "AF",
    "name": "Afghanistan"
  },
  {
    "code": "AX",
    "name": "Aland Islands"
  },
  {
    "code": "AL",
    "name": "Albania"
  }
]
```

I want to map this response data to a Typescript interface that looks like this, and pass it to a reusable `SelectList` component:

```
export interface SelectList {
    data: {
        value: string,
        label: string,
        isSelected: boolean
    }[],
    name: string,
    value: string,
    onChange?: (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => void,
    addClass?: string
}
```

I'm not sure how to map the API response data to the `SelectList` interface?

```
export default function CountrySelectList(props: CountrySelectListProps) {

    const [countries, setCountries] = useState<SelectListModel["data"]>([]);
    const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);

    async function fetchCountriesHandler() {
        try {
            const response = await fetch('api/location/countries');
            if (response.ok) {
                const json = await response.json();
                const countries = json.data.map(
                    // what goes here?
                    // value: json.data.code
                    // label: json.data.name
                );
                setCountries(countries);
                setIsLoaded(true);
            }
        } catch (error: any) {
            setError(error.message);
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchCountriesHandler();
    }, []);

    if (!isLoaded) {
        return (<div>Loading...</div>);
    }

    if (error) {
        return (<div className="">Error: Unable to load countries</div>);
    }

    if (countries.length > 0) {
        return (
            <>
                <FormGroup addClass="form-group">
                    <Label label="country" title="Country" />
                    <SelectList data={countries} name={props.name} value={props.value} onChange={props.onChange} />
                </FormGroup>
            </>
        );
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the response data you sent it would be:

```js
const countries = json.map(row => (
  {
    value: row.code,
    label: row.name,
    isSelected: false
  }
));
```

Your code had an extra `.data.` but based on your sample data that property doesn't exist.